# How to display the one cell containing text in a range of cells containing numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I need some help as I need a formula that will check for a cell containing text in a row of numbers and then display the contents of the cell with text.

Its a table which has 4 columns 3 of which will contain 0 and one will contain either C, R or O.
The table contains 35,000 rows and will be added to weekly.

I need to display the answer at the end of the row.

Example table below:

```
Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Result
0   C   0   0   
0   0   0   R   
0   0   O   0   
0   R   0   0   
0   R   0   0   
0   0   C   0   
0   0   0   C
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly you need to display in `Result` column?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get C, R or O in `Result` column, try to use following formula (I suppose, that your Q1-Q4 are in `A:D` columns):

```
=HLOOKUP("*",A2:D2,1,0)
```

and drag it down.